# If q equals nothing make s equal nothing Javascript

Tags: javascript

This question was answered. But stackoverflow will not let my ask other questions. Can anyone help?

Comment: Could you please do a review of your question. Can't get it

Comment: I tried to figure out what exactly you're trying to do, but I'm not getting it.  You say "V is equal to x", but then you don't have V or x anywhere.

Comment: what is blah blah in this case?? what u want us to assume from this ??

Comment: @user1922274 do not add code as a comment. Edit the question.

Comment: Sorry I want to make it so if q1 equals nothing make s equal nothing as well. I meant v is equal to s (v += s;)

Comment: Wait...what?  You say "v is equal to s", and then follow that immediately with adding s to the value of v (v += s) so that v is very likely not equal to s.  And v doesn't show up in your original code at all.  I think you should go back, and rewrite this question carefully, from scratch.  Explain it from the beginning like you would explain it to your grandmother...you'll make yourself very clear.

Comment: I added more info to my answer. It would be helpful if you posted code, and explained how your variables are being assigned values

Comment: I tried again... showing you how to check a variable to determine if it is undefined. If it is, display nothing in your text field.

Comment: I understand you now... I think I have your solution. I understand it's hard to ask a question when you are a new programmer. Hopefully you will be on the right track now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Declare s and set it to be an empty string by default. If q1 is NOT nothing, then assign a value to s. Otherwise s is still an empty string. Later in your code, you can set your text box to be populated with s, and if q1 is empty, s will be too, so nothing will display there.

```
//declare s and set it to default to an empty string
var s = ''
//make sure q1 is defined and not null
if (q1 != undefined && q1 != null)
   //if q1 is not empty, then set it equal to '_'+n1+'. '+q1, 
   //otherwise s will be an empty string
   if (q1 != '')
       s = '_'+n1+'. '+q1
//if s is empty you can do something, 
//OR you can just set your input value to equal s
if (s == '')
    //do some stuff here
```

Comment: a good answer generally consists of an explanation in addition to some code snippets.

Comment: No not really helpful. I just cant explain what I want. I want it to ignore s completely if q1 equals nothing.

Comment: YOUR A GENIOUS! It worked! I have been trying for like an hour and looked around then I just signed up to ask this thanks so much!

Comment: sweet... I can't remember the restrictions for new users, but if you can, please up vote my answer and mark it correct.

Comment: I did. But now it sticks an undefined in there.

Comment: You need to post the full scope of your code - you can check for undefined, too. Do a google search for JavaScript undefined

Comment: Just debugged and it says NULL is undefined.

Comment: Nevermind put NULL to lowercase it worked. I have tried it thoroughly it works. Thanks for helping me!

Comment: ah yes... I program in a few different languages, so I forgot null was lowercase in JavaScript. You are welcome.